# How to inject service depending on directive attribute in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, typeahead

I have the following directive

```
directiveModule.directive('typeahead', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: 'isolate',
        templateUrl: 'assets/partials/common/typeahead.html' ,
        controller: ["$scope","$element","$attrs","$transclude", "Event", 
        function ($scope,$element,$attrs,$transclude, Event){
            console.log(eval($attrs.service + ".query();"));

            $scope.search = function(){ console.log("Searching for:" + $scope.selectedValue) };
            $scope.selectedValue = "";
            $scope.providedItems = []; 
        }],     
    };
});
```

With the following template:

```
<div>
<input ng-change="search()" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-click="log()" autocomplete="off" type="text"/>
<ul class=".typeahead">
    <li ng-repeat="item in providedItems">{{eval(item + "." + descriptor)}}</li>
</ul>
```

and the following call inside my view:

I would like to let the service attribute be evaluated at runtime when injecting to the controller in the directive. So that where it now says

```
controller: ["$scope","$element","$attrs","$transclude", "Event", 
        function ($scope,$element,$attrs,$transclude, Event){
```

It would say something similar to:

```
controller: ["$scope","$element","$attrs","$transclude", eval($attrs.service), 
        function ($scope,$element,$attrs,$transclude, eval($attrs.service)){
```

However I can't access the $attrs from the scope inside the directiveModule call.

If there is any way to access a service declared in the view that would suffice. Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution for this, would be creating and binding the controller yourself. All you need is to inject both `$injector` (in order to resolve the service dynamically) and `$controller` (in order to resolve the controller dynamically). And in your linking function you create the controller yourself:

```js
link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
  $controller(function YourController($scope, dynamnicService) {
      dynamicService.query();
    }, {
      $scope: scope, 
      dynamicService: $injector.get($attr.service)
    }
  )
}
```

There is one thing important here. I'm considering, in this example, that your service is a string in the element attribute. If it's a string inside the scope, referred by the attribute, then you have to change the approach. You should `$attr.observe` the attribute, and on change, you should grab the service `$injector.get(...)` and pass it to the controller. You ould either create a `this.setService` method on the controller itself, or `$scope.setService` method, your call. I'd rather the controller, as this is related to accessing a service. Using this second approach, you don't need to create the controller by hand, you can simple expose this method and set the data from outside.

One more info, you should [NEVER TOUCH THE DOM FROM YOUR CONTROLLER](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#commonpitfalls). So passing `$element`, `$attr` and `$transculde` to the controller is probably a bad idea, no matter what.

Take a look at the docs about `$controller`, `$injector` and [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more clear im not sure where to start with this. What I need is a way to select the Service to query at runtime.

Comment: From the beginning, what you expect `$attrs.service` to be? Give me an example.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. $attrs.service is an angular service that I want to dynamically inject.

Comment: Have you used the approach I suggested?

Comment: Well kind of ill edit your post to reflect what I had to do is that ok? then ill accept it.